# Monitor multiple Servers Performance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2003, monitoring, mac-osx-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring production server](https://serverfault.com/questions/66757/monitoring-production-server)

In my company there are 5 servers, each one of them is running on different OS such as Linux, Red Hat, Windows, and Mac OS Server.

So my question is, is there a way to monitor performances and utilise the Internet connectivity of all servers at just one computer? I mean something to collect the information of all server and report it in one page or even email?

Is there any software that be so cross platform?

Answer (score 3):

We use a combination of Munin and Nagios which are both free open source products.  They have a bit of a learning curve but are both extremely flexible with lots of plugins and able to support remote servers and email alerts.

Nagios in particular has lots of plugins for Windows and Linux so may suit you well

See http://munin-monitoring.org/ and http://www.nagios.com for more details

Comment: Nagios also works very well with Macs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is, check out:

- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
- [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/)
- [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)
- google: server monitoring

You set up a monitoring server somewhere, install nodes (or use SNMP) to gather data from servers, and set up the required/desired views/graphs/data, and notifications

Comment: thanks for answer, but where should I install these software ? do I need to install it on one by one of each server ?

Comment: You install them on one machine, which will be the monitoring machine. In most cases you will also install a client on each monitored machine, which gets the data from the monitored machines and passes it to the monitoring machine.

Comment: You need a monitoring server where you will see the reports (you can add it to one of the webservers or on a separate server). Then you install a node on each monitored server, and the main, monitoring server pulls data from each node (monitored server), and generates all the graphs/data/etc. visible on the monitoring server.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/munin-node-win32/ <- here is also the windows munin-node