# Akamai log processing

Tags: logging, log-files, logparser

I'm digging through Akamai logs, downloading excel sheets, and then manually joining them so that I can do sorting of data to find top videos and referrers.  Are there any tools you know of to help with this kind of processing?  I'm looking for something like Urchin used to be for Apache logs, but for Akamai logs.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Log delivery option to send you logs in "Combined" format. So you can use any standard tool of your choice (such as awstats or similar).

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/62687/alternatives-to-splunk) may be of help. I think [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) and [Epylog](https://fedorahosted.org/epylog/) seem to do what you're looking for.

Other tools are referenced there and elsewhere that might also be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Sumo Logic, it offers a cloud to cloud integration with Akamai, with rich out-of-the-box content, utilizing cloud monitor. Setup is a breeze, and you don't have to concern yourself with batch downloading/processing anything on-prem.

https://www.sumologic.com/2013/10/09/akamai-and-sumo-logic-integrate-for-real-time-application-insights/

Disclaimer- I am a Sumo Employee.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a ton of `awk`, `sort` and `uniq -c` when doing things like this.

Perl can be great for repeatability, but be careful, when dealing with large data sets (I've recently been playing with BGP dumps from a DFZ router) it's *really* easy to push even a big machine into swap if you leak any memory.

Tools like Splunk etc. seem like they might be nice for ad-hoc stuff where a simple unix pipe might not work, but don't appear to be a good solution for more permanent reports.

You could simply use Awstats or similar, most web log processing tools can be told to to use a different input format.