# Free / Open Source -- Log Management appliances/platforms

Tags: logging, syslog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to Splunk?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62687/alternatives-to-splunk)

I need to deploy a centralized log management device or appliance.  It should be able to handle at least 100 devices giving it input.  I would also like the ability for it to send me alerts when certain things are caught.

I have looked at splunk and free splunk doesn't alert you.  Any other ideas?
It can run on either windows or linux it doesn't matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183977/what-commercial-and-open-source-competitors-are-there-to-splunk/

Answer (score 2):

Although not strictly "log management", another possibility in managing large networks of devices is a monitoring system. In many cases it's useful to know now only if a device is reporting "error" or "ok" with a service, but also if that service (and the machine it's running on) is completely inaccessible. Systems like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) and Zenoss (http://www.zenoss.com/) (both have open source and enterprise editions) will alert you of problems and can also parse logs to report problems that way too.

Comment: +1, What supervacuo is hinting at here is that logs are NOT the channel for monitoring i.e. alerting - they are diagnostic/auditing tools.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my spaghetti-verbiage! 

That's exactly what I'm trying to say — log parsing to get alerts is inserting an almost-always-unnecessary step in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could try syslog-ng store box appliance.

http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/log-server-appliance/

You could also simply do this with syslog-ng afcourse but the above is turnkey appliance.

Answer (score 1):

Give LogZilla a try (http://www.logzilla.pro), my company has been using for a year now and I love it. It does have built-in alerting capability.

Answer (score 0):

Try CorreLog.  Here is the link for the 30 day evaluation version.  http://www.correlog.com/purchase/free-trial-download-form.html

Security event correlation, consolidation of logs, any platform.  Check them out.

Answer (score 0):

I have liked using Epylog:

http://packages.debian.org/sid/epylog

You can write regex to catch what you wish and then act on it.  Just central syslog the data and run epylog on a schedule.