# Best tools for "ssh tail -f" style log file monitoring and analysis

Tags: ssh, monitoring, logging, remote, tail

I'm looking for a tool to monitor custom PHP Error logs/Apache and possibly Java logs on remote development servers.

I'm not looking for a full production log system like Splunk, but something that's a little more flexible than an ssh terminal doing a "tail -f".

Perhaps something that will:
 * Monitor multiple log files to my local machine for searching/analysis later
 * Allow "alerts" when certain strings appear in the log
 * Provide some kind of tabbed/dashboard view of the multiple logs being monitored (in total less than 10 logs).

Answer (score 1):

I would take a second look at Splunk. With that amount of data I think you will be happy with the [free version](http://www.splunk.com/view/free-vs-enterprise/SP-CAAAE8W). I would be scared away by "full production version" as it is pretty easy to set up.

It is pretty straight forward to set up "dashboards" as well which give you the custom view you are looking for.

The real downside is that the free version doesn't meet your requirement for alerting. Really though you could rig that up with a cron job and grep script pretty easily.

You might also find something in [alternatives to Splunk](https://serverfault.com/questions/62687/alternatives-to-splunk).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a **cloud-based** logging service, we have something for you at [Loggly](http://www.loggly.com). You can signup for a free account to try it out at no cost.

We would use a small script tool that you can run on your machine to tail the logs (or even better, you setup your log source to output syslog) and send all the data to our cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout in'side log.

A Java tool I created, able to read local and distant log files using SSH. It is fairly simple to use.

Some more explanations: https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/wiki

Just download the version corresponding to your operating system, or the native jar release executable within your Java Runtime (requires java 8_40 or higher):

https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/releases

You can find a complete documentation (embedded with and in Github's page as well)