# tool to analyse/grep  log files

Tags: log-files, grep, tail

Is there any web based GUIs to analyse or in realtime filter/grep log files from apache? log files that are access logs or error logs or postfix logs etc.

Edit: I don't mean traffic analysis. Much more about greping error logs to locate some error trails. locating php fatal errors, or Exceptions in error logs which is mostly a tail+grep exersize.

Comment: Splunk, phpsyslog-ng, ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing one - [tailon](https://github.com/gvalkov/tailon). It's a simple web interface to `tail -f` and `tail -f | {awk,grep,sed}`.

Answer (score 1):

Webalyzer, Urchin, Google Analytics (via upload), AWStats just to name a few. These will parse and visualize your log data. (For web stuff)

If you want something 'nifty' but limited in practicality, look at [Logstalgia](http://code.google.com/p/logstalgia/).

For any and all logs, there's not too much and it's [answered elsewhere on this site](https://serverfault.com/questions/62687/alternatives-to-splunk)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another one - [Loganalyzer](http://loganalyzer.adiscon.com/)