# Logcheck alternative for central syslog server

Tags: logging, syslog

I have to setup some open source log monitoring on a centralized syslog server.
A lot of machines (windows, linux) and some routers and switches sending their logs there.

Many years ago when I had to do similar setup I used logcheck which is the improved version of logsentry but I'm sure there are many free alternatives for this out there.

I do not need fancy stuff like storing events in database or displaying them on some web frontend. All I need is an easy to configure solution which regularly goes through all the machines logs, find suspicious events in them and send me an email about them. 
I need a tool which can be easily configured to ignore all the "noise". I don't want to receive hundreds of emails from this every day.

What I found so far:

logcheck, logtail, logsentry, Swatch, SEC, OSSEC

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Splunk?](http://serverfault.com/questions/62687/alternatives-to-splunk)

Answer (score 1):

- Logstash -> Kibana,
- Logstash -> Greylog2
- Logstash -> just about anything else

http://edgeofsanity.net/article/2012/06/17/central-logging-with-open-source-software.html

You may want to move this post to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: came here to say Logstash. It can be a bear to get up and running, depending on size, but it works great.